# How to fix this error in while loop in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list in Python, `list1`, and the following while loop:

```
j = 0
while list1[j] >= list1[j - 1] and j < len(list1):
    # do something here and return k
    # k is always incremented
    j += k
```

I got the following error:
`IndexError: string index out of range`

How to fix this error?

Comment: change `j = 0` to `j = 1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to start your while condition with the length check.  Python [short-circuits](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) the operations in your while loop, so when `j` is too large, it will just throw an error rather than gracefully ending the loop.  So like this:

```
while j < len(list1) and list1[j] >= list1[j - 1]:
```

Your first iteration of the loop is comparing `list1[0]` and `list1[-1]`, which is *valid*, but may not be what you want to be doing (it compares the first and last elements of `list1`).  Depending on your goals, you may or may not wish to start your loop with `j = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

When using an `and`, if the first condition is false, the second is not even checked. Simply use:

```
j = 0
while j < len(list1) and list1[j] >= list1[j - 1]:
    # do something here and return k
    # k is always incremented
    j += k
```